# Getting configuration strings from Weblogic

Tags: weblogic, jndi, weblogic12c

This question is related to **Weblogic 12c**.

I have an EAR file that I want to deploy in various environments (*dev*, *QA*, *pre-prod* and *prod*). However, my application requires a *username* and a *password* (to connect to another server) and they're not the same across the four environments.  I don't want to package 4 different property files in 4 different EAR files. I want a single generic EAR file. Beside, I don't want to handle the prod password during packaging.

Ideally, I'd like the admin of each environment to provide the appropriate username nad password for the environment. Unlike Tomcat, Jetty or JBoss(?), I think it's not possible for a WebLogic Admin to specify this information in a way that it will become available under the java:comp/env JNDI context.

How can an application obtain some admin-defined configuration strings from Weblogic?

BTW, it's **not** a username/password for a JDBC connection.

Answer (score 2):

From what I understand, you need to change parameters based on the environment you are using right?
If you would like to override parameterss on the fly you can use WebLogic deployment plan concept.

Comment: Interesting... Would that allow me to change servlet context parameters or servlet init parameters of a web module within an EAR file?

Comment: @gawi Please have a look into [Configuring Applications for Production Deployment](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11035_01/wls100/deployment/config.html). It looks like the admins of your environments will need to configure each deployment plan for themselves. I have not used a deployment plan to store credentials, though. Since it is a XML file (not sure whether it supports encryption or not), maybe it would not be a good idea to store credentials on it, but that depends on your security constraints.

Comment: @Viccari Indeed. How does one manage envrionment-dependent credentials with Weblogic? As far as I know, that problem has only been solved properly for JDBC (i.e. the connections pools configured by the admin on the server, not by the developper). On IBM Websphere App Server, I've used J2C to access admin-provided credentials. I'm clueless regarding Weblogic on that matter.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean that you need to provide username/password to start-up the application?
If so, you may accomplish that by creating a script with WLST http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15051_01/wls/docs103/config_scripting/using_WLST.html

Comment: No. A username password is required to make a TCP connection (custom protocol) to another server.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the WebLogic way is to

- Define your username/password as `env-entry` in the deployment descriptor
- Deploy your application together with the `plan.mxl` whereas each environment admin maintains his own envrionemnt-specific version of the `plan.xml`

That way you get them into `/comp/env/config`

More details here: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11035_01/wls100/deployment/config.html

Only drawback known to me: `plan.xml` will always contain the unencrypted password but as the admin knows the password anyway and this is "his" file on "his" maschine that should be fine.